# three dropdown box related to eachother

Tags: laravel

i have three dropdown box each box is dependent to eachother 
if i click one dropdown means heading want to display next dropdown box that heading related topics want to display in third dropdown box that topics reaming topics want to display

for.ex: first dropdown box i have fruit and anmials  if i click fruit means second dropdown box will display the fruit name like banana, apple, orange then i click banana means the third dropdown box display remains apple and orange want to display

Comment: you should use js to do this. you can't do it only with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Vue to fill the next dropbox according to the prev one.
You have to read about:

- [Writing vue components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-vue-components)
- [VueJs](https://vuejs.org/)